# R package fails CRAN check on r-devel windows because of missing dependencies

Tags: r

I recently submitted an R package to CRAN which passed the initial checks and was published on CRAN. But it fails a package check on one of the configurations it was tested on by CRAN, `r-devel-windows-x86_64-gcc10-UCRT`. (https://cran.r-project.org/web/checks/check_results_rslurm.html)

Our package has one hard dependency, `whisker`. The dependency isn't available for some reason on that combination of OS and R version.

The relevant section of the `DESCRIPTION` file is:

```
Imports:
    whisker (>= 0.3)
```

I didn't think this was a big concern because it's an unstable development version of R. But unfortunately the ["CRAN badge"](https://usethis.r-lib.org/reference/badges.html) on our [package site](https://cyberhelp.sesync.org/rslurm/) shows a big ugly red ERROR now.

Is this something that will resolve itself with time or should I contact the developer of `whisker`? Relatedly, would this require me to submit a patch release to CRAN to fix it?

Comment: Has CRAN contacted you about this? If so, you need to worry about it. If not, you don't

Comment: No they haven't. It's just too bad that the [badge](https://usethis.r-lib.org/reference/badges.html) says "error." It is a bad look for potential users who visit our package site. Are we doomed to see that until the next release?

Comment: So remove the badge. Most packages will show an error on that build right now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is an experimental build.  If your package fails on it because of a missing dependency, don't worry about it.  If it fails for some other reason, you should fix it.

You can read the details here:  https://www.r-project.org/nosvn/winutf8/ucrt3/CRAN/checks/gcc10-UCRT/README.txt and here:  https://svn.r-project.org/R-dev-web/trunk/WindowsBuilds/winutf8/ucrt3/howto.html .

Your package fails only because of a missing dependency.  If you want to get rid of that badge, you could help the dependency author to fix their package so it builds.  In the case of `whisker` it's also a dependency issue, so it may take a bit of time to trace back through the dependencies until you find the package(s) that actually fail and are fixable, but perhaps you could inform the `whisker` author of the issue, hopefully to recruit them in the search.